# HTTP Request Headers set as LinkedList in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, http, httprequest, spring-integration

We are trying to set the request parameters from an HTTP inbound request to the header. We have managed to successfully set the request value to the header, however it is not set in the way we want.

The request header mapping value is set to the message header as a java.util.LinkedList instead of String which is the expected request parameter type.

The following is the configuration

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundApplicationDataRequestGateway"
        supported-methods="GET"
        request-channel="applicationDataRequest"
        reply-channel="applicationDataResponse"
        mapped-response-headers="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS"
        path="/services/application/that/data"
        reply-timeout="50000">

            <int-http:header name="dataVersion" expression="#requestParams['data_version']"/>
        </int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator id="applicationDataServiceActivator"
                    input-channel="applicationDataRequest"
                    output-channel="applicationDataResponse"
                    ref="dataService"
                    method="getData"
                    requires-reply="false"
                    send-timeout="60000"/>
```

The following is the sample service method

```
public void getData(Message<?> inMessage){
        MessageHeaders headers = inMessage.getHeaders();
        logger.info("DATA VERSION : " + (String)headers.get("dataVersion"));
    }
```

The following is the stacktrace

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
```

**How can we have dataVersion set as a string instead of a linked list?**

Also we would need to do the following for POST requests in other http inbound gateway methods as well

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
MilindaD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `servletRequest.getParameterMap()` returns `Map<String, String[]>` and Spring Integration converts it to the `MultiValueMap<String, String>`. And when you ask it to `get` some value it really returns `LinkedList<String>`.

So, to get only single value from that `List` (and here you are really sure that there is only one item) you should use this:

```
<int-http:header name="dataVersion" expression="#requestParams.getFirst('data_version')"/>
```